# Understanding backboneJS: View.extend()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

Until today I thought using backbones functionality like

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $.Deferred,
    getTemplate: function(tplName) {
        var self = this;
        ajaxCall(tplName).then(function(hbs) {
            self.template.resolve(hbs);
        });
    }
});

var home = new PageView();
home.getTemplate('home.hbs');
```

is similar to a pure JS OOP approach like

```
var PageView = function() {
    this.template = $.Deferred();
}

PageView.prototype.getTemplate = function(tplName) {
    var self = this;
    ajaxCall(tplName).then(function(hbs) {
        self.template.resolve(hbs);
    });
}

var home = new PageView();
home.getTemplate('home.hbs');
```

However, I'm currently trying to rebuild a web-app with backbone and it seems like solving that deferred with

```
home.getTemplate('home.hbs');
```

will resolve this for all instances of the Backbone view `PageView` while in pure JS this would only resolve for that one particular instance `home`.

When I do a second instance:

```
var page1 = new PageView();
```

the `template` property is already resolved with the `home.hbs` template in backbone. Which is very weird to me.

So my guess is that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how backbone views work.
Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: This seems related to one of my favorite js questions: [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: @mrak wtf I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for sharing this question! Definitely opened my eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the first snippet `template` property of all the instances refer to the same object and in the second snippet the property is set using a different/new instance of Deferred when the constructor function is executed. If you set the `template` property within the `initialize` function of the constructor you will get the same result as the second snippet:

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // template: $.Deferred,
    initialize: function() {
       this.template = $.Deferred;
    },
    getTemplate: function(tplName) {
        var self = this;
        ajaxCall(tplName).then(function(hbs) {
            self.template.resolve(hbs);
        });
    }
});
```

In the second example if you set the `template` to the `prototype` of the constructor then it will behave like the backbone constructor:

```
var PageView = function() {
   // this.template = $.Deferred();
}
PageView.prototype.template = $.Deferred();

var instance1 = new PageView();
var instance2 = new PageView();
console.log( instance1.template === instance2.template ); // true
```

Comment: worksl ike a charm! So properties and their values of backbone views are shared accross instances?
Thank you for explaining this to me!